# How can I make an external drive behave as an internal drive?

Tags: terminal, finder, macos, external-disk

My question is pretty much summed up by the title, I have an external drive which I'd like to have recognized as an internal drive. How can I do that? Thanks for looking at my question. By the way I am running 10.11.3 on mbp

Answer (score -1):

I just found this answer, sorry I tried looking first but couldn't find it....

You should be able to do this with dd by setting Removable to False.

Unmount your disk, then run…

**dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 bs=1 count=1**

Don't forget to replace disk2 with the actual disk identifier.

This command will erase the contents of the disk. Untested, be careful, usual 'not responsible if stuff goes wrong' applies :)

Comment: Well first I guess I should say that the drive was empty, but what do you mean by an install, install what?

Comment: @Gene: Doesn't bs=1 mean 1 byte? And with count=1, wouldn't that mean to just write a value of zero to the first byte of the disk?

Comment: This answer is probably wrong. Byte 0 (the first byte of the first block is apparently always zero). Additionally this will probably **not** erase your disk!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I tried it and even though I couldn't tell if the drive was erased since it was empty. Disk Utility does label it as an Internal Physical Volume...